# loop through settimeout with stetimeout function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, settimeout

Not sure if it is the best way to do it, but here's what I am trying:

**Example Code:**

```
$("#someElement").mouseout(function() {
    var firstLoop = setTimeout(function() {
        //do something
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(function() {
        //do something else
    }, 4000);

    var timer = 1000;
    setTimeout(firstLoop, timer); //this doesn't works
});
```

I am trying to loop this infinitely.

Comment: A typo perhaps? `timeout`?

Comment: Are you looking for `setInterval` instead ?

Comment: Sorry, typo was only in my question.

Comment: @Striped tried `setInterval` also. Didn't work.

Comment: what is your goal?

Comment: @arnoldemzi goal is to loop infinitely with both timeout, so, the first function then second then first then second.. and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> setTimeout(firstLoop, timer); //this doesn't works

because `setTimeout` (`firstLoop`) doesn't return a function reference which `setTimeout` expects.

Make it

```
var firstLoop = function(){ 
  setTimeout(function() {
    //do something
  }, 2000);
}
```

**From your comment**

> @arnoldemzi goal is to loop infinitely with both timeout, so, the
>   first function then second then first then second.. and so on.

Just use `setInterval`

```
$("#someElement").mouseout(function() {
    var firstLoop = function() {
        console.log( "something" );
    };

    setTimeout(function() {
        //do something else
    }, 4000);

    var timer = 1000;
    setInterval(firstLoop, timer); //this doesn't works
});
```

Comment: For your edit: Will that setInterval call setTimeout also?

Comment: @Saurabh No, there is no reason to. If you are looking for infinite looping, then keep it simple with `setInterval`.

Comment: Awesome, Understood.

Answer (score 0):

You would use setInterval if you would like something to repeat on an interval, and pass it the function you'd like to repeat as well as the interval in milliseconds.

I've changed your code ever so slightly as to demonstrate this:

```
$('button').click(function() {

    var firstLoop = function() {
        console.log('first')
    };

    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('second')
    }, 4000);

    var timer = 1000;
    setInterval(firstLoop, timer);
});
```

See a working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/hgnm1mph/3/